# How to align image to bottom in Latex

Tags: javascript, ide, latex, miktex, texmaker

I am trying to create a document in Latex (MiKTex) using Texmaker for Linear Algebra. I wrote some text in page and now want to adjust picture in bottom of that text but picture goes to up the text automatically.

This is output of the code in this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIsWC.jpg)

There is code:

```
\begin{Large}

\justify
LaTeX is a software system for document preparation. When writing, the writer uses plain text as opposed to the formatted text found in "What You See Is What You Get" word processors like Microsoft Word, LibreOffice Writer and Apple Pages.\\
\\LaTeX is widely used in academia for the communication and publication of scientific documents in many fields, including mathematics, statistics, computer science, engineering, physics, economics, linguistics, quantitative psychology, philosophy, and political science. It also has a prominent role in the preparation and publication of books and articles that contain complex multilingual materials, such as Sanskrit and Greek. LaTeX uses the TeX typesetting program for formatting its output, and is itself written in the TeX macro language.\\
\\To download and install Latex we have to download two software, one is MiKTeX and second one is Texmaker, in first steps we will download and install MiKTex and then we will install Texmaker.
\end{Large}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{Large}
\textbf{Step 1:}\\
\end{Large}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{Large}
\begin{flushleft}
First you need to go to Google search bar and search MiKTex Download.
\end{flushleft}
\end{Large}

\begin{figure}

\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Mik1.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: here is an extra community for latex

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Just a guess because you don't show us compilable code to test: maybe try a floating specifier such as `\begin{figure}[b]` if you want the image at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

You should add the float package (\usepackage{float}) in your preamble and then add the floating specifier to your figure (\begin{figure}[b])

The basic specifiers:
h - places the float here, i.e., approximately at the same point it occurs in the source text (however, not exactly at the spot);
t - positions it at the top of the page;
b - positions it at the bottom of the page.

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_of_Figures

Comment: You don't need the `float` package for `[b]`